# Why doesn't GeckoFX Navigate() request work if launched in a seperate thread?

Tags: c#, .net, browser, multithreading, geckofx

Why does this work,

```
    private void buttonBoo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GeckoBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com/");
    }
```

and this not?

```
    private void buttonBoo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            GeckoBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com/");
        });

        thread.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

GeckoBrowser is a Windows Forms Control.  A Control's properties and methods may be called only from the thread on which the Control was created.  To do anything with a Control from another thread, you need to use the Invoke or BeginInvoke method, e.g.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
{
  Action<string> action = url => GeckoBrowser.Navigate(url);
  GeckoBrowser.Invoke(action, new object[] { "http://www.google.com/" });
});
```

Comment: Sorry to necro, but does this apply even when the browser itself was initialized (and all actions as well!) are performed on a (STA) thread created from a MTA application? Everything GeckoFx related happens on a separate thread with no cross-thread use. The .Navigate(...); function is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that due to the underlying engine, XulRunner (XPCOM), the GeckoFX component is NOT generally multithreadable. This is because XulRunner, itself, is a single threaded runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because Geckofx in itself doesn't support cross Threading if you want to do cross thread you will need to Invoke it first.

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
         this.Invoke(new Action(() => {GeckoBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com/");}));
    });
```